# Insert from another db where entry doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the same database, one newer, one older.

I need to copy any new rows from the newer db into the older db.

Each row has a `entry_id` so I am looking for a way to check if this exists before copying that row.

I was thinking that maybe `WHERE NO EXISTS` would be what I need, but I can't figure out how to do this when copying from another db.

```
INSERT INTO lightand_expressionengine.exp_channel_data
FROM lightand_expressionengineold.exp_channel_data
WHERE NOT EXISTS ()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO lightand_expressionengine.exp_channel_data(col1, . . . coln)
    select col1, . . . coln
    FROM lightand_expressionengineold.exp_channel_data o
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1
                      from lightand_expressionengine.exp_channel_data n
                      where o.id = n.id
                     );
```

This just checks one field (`id`).  You might have other conditions.

Comment: Thanks. How would I say to insert into every column, from every column. Would it just be a case of (*) on the top two lines to replace col1,...coln)?

Comment: @user2889310 . . . Yes.  You can use `*`, assuming both tables have the same columns in the same order.